# How to add a shortcut to "update status" of Broadcast/Gwibber configuration in Ubuntu

Tags: shortcuts

In the taskbar at the top of Ubuntu, upon clicking the mail icon, there is an option called `Broadcast` which when configured gwibber with twitter account adds up an additional option in the menu just below `broadcast` called "`Update Status`".

Clicking the update status option pops up a tiny window with textbox to update twitter status. I find this very nice. Except that I feel it is more comfortable to have a shortcut configured for this. How do I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific application that launches when you click "Update Status" is called *gwibber-poster*. The actual application that handles the Broadcast accounts in Ubuntu is (by default) Gwibber.

To give it a keyboard shortcut, simply open up System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, and create a custom shortcut for the command *gwibber-poster*. I don't have enough rep to post images yet, but here's a link to the image so you know what I'm talking about: [Custom Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk0y9.png)

Funny enough, I actually figured this out because I was looking up the exact same question. I knew the application was Gwibber, I just didn't know whether there was an option or another command that launched specifically that "Update Status" dialog. So, I typed "gwibber" into a terminal window and hit Tab until it showed me the available commands that started with "gwibber". That's when I saw "gwibber-poster" and decided to give it a shot. Glad I found out about this. Hope it helps somebody else!